# Get mapped network drives labels

Tags: powershell, networking, label, drive, mapped-drive

Is there a way to get mapped network drives labels?
I know it's possible to get multiple properties through the

```
Get-Object Win32_MappedLogicalDisk
```

But none of them are labels (please do not misunderstand, I do not want Name i.e. K:, I want labels i.e. My Network drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Com Shell.Application object for this:

```
$shell  = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk).DeviceID | 
# or (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk).DeviceID | 
# or ([System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 'Network' }).Name |
Select-Object @{Name = 'Drive'; Expression = {$_}},
              @{Name = 'Label'; Expression = {$shell.NameSpace("$_").Self.Name.Split("(")[0].Trim()}}

# when done, clear the com object from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Output:

```
Drive Label     
----- -----     
X:    MyCode
```

---

Some explanation for the above:

Using the COM object Shell.Application, you can drill down through its properties and methods.

```
.NameSpace  create and return a Folder object for the specified folder
.Self       gets a Read-Only duplicate System.Shell.Folder object
.Name       from that we take the Name property like 'MyCode (X:)'
.Split      this name we split on the opening bracket '(',
[0]         take the first part of the splitted name and 
.Trim()     get rid of any extraneous whitespace characters
```

Another way is to go into the registry, but remember that after a mapped network folder is unmapped, the old registry value remains.
This is why below code still uses one of two methods to find active network mappings first:

```
# the registry key to search in
$regKey = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2'

# list the mapped network drives and loop through
# you can also use Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | ForEach-Object {
    # create the full registry key by replacing the backslashes in the network path with hash-symbols
    $key = Join-Path -Path $regKey -ChildPath ($_.ProviderName -replace '\\', '#')
    # return an object with the drive name (like 'X:') and the Label the user gave it
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Drive = $_.DeviceID  
        Label = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $key -Name '_LabelFromReg' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

Output here also:

```
Drive Label 
----- ----- 
X:    MyCode
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried all of your suggestions, and they all work, except not the way I want it. It returns the name of the drive that the shared resource is on. What I want is the value of registry key mentoned by @pmooo00, which is the name user gives to the mapped drive

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by Label.. I have changed the code now to hopefully get what you need

Comment: Wow, that indeed does what I want but is way out of my league. Would you mind explaining of referring me to literature that might help?

Comment: What I've managed to get is "_LabelFromReg" value for every "shared" folder on my PC.

Comment: `$(if ((test-path -Path "HKU:") -eq $false){New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS})|Out-Null

$path = 'HKU:\S-1-5-21-2123692221-2998377337-916390259-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2' 
$s = Get-Childitem -Path $path |Where-object {$_.Name -match '#'} |Select -ExpandProperty Name 
$s1 = $s.Substring(121)


foreach ($s2 in $s1){Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKU:\S-1-5-21-2123692221-2998377337-916390259-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\$s2" "_LabelFromReg"}`

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb I'm on mobile now, so for now all I can do is give you the link to the [Shell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell). I'll try and add some explanation tomorrow. About your code, although difficult to read in a comment, you are doing that the hard way I think by using `HKU:`.  Wouldn't `HKCU:` be a lot easier, so you don't need to append your user SID?

Comment: What you created here amazes me, truly.
I have one other question. Is it possible to assing this function output to array/variable to be used in combobox dropdown?

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb Sure, simply capture the result in a variable like `$mappedDrives = Get-WmiObject  ...`. After that, you can loop through this variable and populate your combobox like this: `$mappedDrives | ForEach-Object { $myComboBox.Items.Add($_.Label) }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a cmdlet that will give you that info. I believe you can find it by looking at the registry with gci, but you would need to cleanup the output.

```
get-childitem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2"
```

Comment: I am aware of that location in registry. I hoped there was an easier way than one involving MountPoints2. Thanks nonetheless