# System.__ComObject to string or variable

Tags: powershell, shell, variables, com, output

I writing a GUI script concerning mapped drives. What I'd like to do is to get the label text to change in accordance with combobox selection and display drive label. To get the label I use COM Shell.Application, but for the love of me I cannot get the output to be a string or a variable.

```
$A = 'H:' #Example drive
$sh=New-Object -com Shell.Application
$sh.NameSpace($A).Self.Name.Split("(")[0].Trim()}
```

Output when I run script 'MSZ' is the label of H: drive

```
PS C:\Users\Axel\Desktop> C:\Users\Axel\Desktop\TESTY\Nazwa Zmapowanego dysku 1.1.ps1
MSZ
```

But when i try to use $sh in write-host I get

```
PS C:\Users\Axel\Desktop> C:\Users\Axel\Desktop\TESTY\Nazwa Zmapowanego dysku 1.1.ps1
MSZ
System.__ComObject
```

How do I get rid of System.__ComObject at the end of output?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `Get-PSDrive`?

Comment: Yes, Get-PSDrive will not give me a label (i.e. THIS IS MY DRIVE)

Comment: @Nawad-sama - you very definitely CAN get the drive label from that cmdlet. lookee >>> `(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Name 'D').Description` <<< ///// on my system that gives `D-Drive`. [*grin*]

Comment: Agree with Lee_Dailey unless you have the default name (like `Local Disk (X:)`) then you would see an empty property.

Comment: Because variable `$sh` is the COM object itself, created with `$sh = New-Object -com Shell.Application`. If you want to capture the disk label in a variable, simply do `$label = $sh.NameSpace($A).Self.Name.Split("(")[0].Trim()`. Also do not forget to clear the COM object from memory with `ReleaseComObject` as I have shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67949220/9898643)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that works, but only for local drives, for C: it gives 'Widnows' as description, but for mapped drive it comes back empty

Comment: Hi again @Theo, your previous solution worked but not the way I wanted. This is it. Thank you

Comment: @Nawad-sama - _for me_, the drive label of the `c` drive is shown in the `.Description` property - and it shows `C-Drive` ... which is the label i gave it. i don't have a network, so i cannot test the mapped drive problem. ///// i see you have a workaround, so i will go back t lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]